# Программа с автозапуском при старте пк не читает json

Tags: c#, wpf

Регистрирую программу в реестре следующем образом. При запуске системы программа стартует, но записи пустые.

```
  RegistryKey reg;
  reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\", true);
  reg.SetValue("organaizer", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

---

mainWindows.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
   var vm = new MainViewModel();
   vm.Initialize(this);
   DataContext = vm;
}
```

В самой MainViewModel запускается функция

```
public static void Load(ObservableCollection<ItemInfoCard> _itemInfoCards)
{
    if (File.Exists(dirFile))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(dirFile))
        {
            string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if(json.Length > 1)
            {
                dynamic jsonDes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                foreach (var item in jsonDes)
                {
                    bool isExist = true;
                    //Проверка на существование файла
                    if ((E_CategoryGroup)item.CategoryGroup == E_CategoryGroup.exe)
                    {
                        if (!File.Exists((string)item.Location))
                        {
                            isExist = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if ((E_CategoryGroup)item.CategoryGroup == E_CategoryGroup.dir)
                    {
                        if (!Directory.Exists((string)item.Location))
                        {
                            isExist = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isExist)
                    {
                        if (item.LocationIcon == null)
                        {
                            _itemInfoCards.Add(new ItemInfoCard(
                            (E_CategoryGroup)item.CategoryGroup,
                            (bool)item.IsFavorite,
                            (string)item.Name,
                            (string)item.Location
                            ));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _itemInfoCards.Add(new ItemInfoCard(
                            (E_CategoryGroup)item.CategoryGroup,
                            (bool)item.IsFavorite,
                            (string)item.Name,
                            (string)item.Location,
                            (string)item.LocationIcon
                            ));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки и строчку в которой она возникает

Comment: @aepot в том то и дело что ошибок нету

Comment: это вам привет от динамиков. Научитесь десереализовать JSON https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to, JSON.NET устарел, dynamic зло

Comment: @aepot не может найти файл

Comment: вот в этой строчке проблема if (File.Exists(dirFile))

Comment: Он ссылается на путь C:\Windows\system32\save.json ... хотя указано вот так
 dirFile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/save.json";

Comment: Ну тогда вы уже поняли проблему, текущий каталог и каталог запуска приложения - 2 большие разницы.

Comment: @aepot странно но программа не находиться по пути C:\Windows\system32\ Каким образом этот путь взялся ?

Comment: Это текущий каталог. От текущего каталога работают все относительные пути. почему он именно такой - вопрос к разработчикам Windows.

Comment: Это помогло решить проблему. Я заменил `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` на `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`